# Changewatcher in flex3.0?how to use in below mentioned Situation

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, flex3

Please tell me about the change watcher in flex.
i have a situation like,

i have few canvas, on which i have to show select and unselect,(These canvas hold product thumbnail images) , so when some thumbnail is selected i have to show selection and on selecting other, i have to unselect the previously selected canvas and have to select other

here rollover and rollout on canvas are also working

Here i have to use changewatcher, as one canvas lost the selection and next gets the selection, so some changewatcher gets called

so pleasse if n e one has done this, plzz help me

thanx in Advance

tc

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's a simpler way of doing this. You could create some bindable variable that you can set to the current selected component. This way, you could declare the component such as:

```
<component id="product1" selected="{currentSelectedComponent == product1}" />
```